# UItableView Problem in deleting items from database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am using in UitableView database.My table view works successfully (add single item,add multiple item,delete all) only problem is there when i want to delete single item for this i using Uitableview edit option.
so how i add database method for deleting single item from database and also from table view.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

implement this part of the protocol:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and in it, save the updates (in your case delete the records) to the database.

Comment: If this worked for you feel free to 'accept' the answer :)
thanks